# Grouped Stacked Bar Chart using MpChart

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have implemented BarChart and my Bar Chart is Grouped and Stacked.
[image: Just Like this Graph]

I am done with Grouping and Stacking BarChart using MpChart Library in Android.
But I am unable to find a way of giving a different color to each bar and each stack.
Currently, I am able to set stack color. But I also want to assign a different color to each bar in a group.
I hope I explained well.

**Update**
[Android Stacked grouped Bar Chart Kotlin Example](http://developine.com/android-grouped-stacked-bar-chart-using-mpchart-kotlin/)

Comment: The link provided is redirecting to some dangerous phishing site. Please repair or remove the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

treat each bar as a different barSet and set color to it.

Comment: Thank you for clue @Atif . I did same and it worked :)

Comment: this should be in comments, it cannot be treated as an answer

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi : Hello Atif, I want to develop this chart on android through java code, please help me, it would be great appreciated.